# Copy a Directory and its content to another Directory

Tags: php

I have set up a form which takes one input, which is set as the name of the new Directory.

Here is where I am creating the new directory.

```
$jobDirectory = $_POST['directory'];

if (!mkdir($jobDirectory, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Now the directory is created I want to copy another directory and its contents into this.

This is the code I have for to do this.

```
copy_directory('template', $jobDirectory.'/template');

function copy_directory($src,$dst) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
            else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

Once this is all run, The new Directory is created, the copy of the other directory is inside  but the contents of the copied directory is not there. Cant figure out if there is something I may have missed out or just a silly mistake.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if you are on linux then try `exec('cp -r $src $dest')`  code.

Comment: I'm not on linux unfortunately, but thanks.